# It doesn't throw an error on invalid input

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KKRIT
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Здравствуйте! Выберите страницу (от 1 до 354):");
            string page = Console.ReadLine();
            int result = Int32.Parse(page);
            while (page <= 1 || page >= 354)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Страница введена успешно");
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Такой страницы не существует");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Переходим на страницу {0}...", page);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If the input is incorrect, the else text is not displayed

I have already tried all the options from the Internet, repeated the format, but nothing comes out

Comment: The code you've provided isn't valid and won't compile (there is no `if` paired with your `else`).

Comment: you have provided an else clause  without an if statement. The code you provided isn't complete and we won't be able to provide any help like that. You'll also need to specify what you mean by incorrect input. Is it a number out of the bounds (1-354) or are you talking about some other input that is not even a valid integer?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the limit from 1 to 354, I realized my mistake, thanks

Comment: How does that even compile? You ahve an `else` without an `if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statements is not right. It should check if page is above or equal to 1 `AND` below or equal to 354 (Then page is existing).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Здравствуйте! Выберите страницу (от 1 до 354):");
    string page = Console.ReadLine();
    int result = Int32.Parse(page);
    if (result >= 1 && result <= 354)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Страница введена успешно");
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid page
        Console.WriteLine("Такой страницы не существует");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Переходим на страницу {0}...", page);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You could switch the `if` statement and check if page is below 1 `OR` above 354 and then print `Invalid page`

```
if (result < 1 || result > 354)
{
    // Invalid page
    Console.WriteLine("Такой страницы не существует");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Страница введена успешно");
}
```